# Sequelize() doesn't return an instance of sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-auto

I recently started using `Sequelize` to get a model of my postgresql database.
To map the database I am using `sequelize-auto`.
I was able to create an auto generated mapping of my db using sequelize-auto when I sent my arguments this way to its constructor:

init.js

```
let sequelizeAutoInstance = new SequelizeAuto(dbName,username,password,options)
```

But it doesn't work when I try to send an instance of `Sequelize` this way:

new-init.js

```
let sequelizeInstance = new Sequelize(sequelizeOptions);
sequelizeAutoInstance = new SequelizeAuto(sequelizeInstance)
```

Looking into `sequelize-auto` ctor I saw it runs those lines:

```
if (database instanceof Sequelize) {
    this.sequelize = database;
}
```

but the instance returning form new Sequelize doesn't return an instance of Sequelize.

What did I miss?
thanks

Comment: could it be on your init.js you misspell your 'username' to 'usernmae' ?

Comment: no It's not that :) I misspelled it when writing the post here. fixed it

Answer (score 1):

If I got you correct. You need to pass an instance of sequelize to your models. If you are using extension models you can simply pass in the instance into the init options.

```js
const { Sequelize, DataTypes, Model } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require("../your/db/file");

class User extends Model {}

User.init({
  // Model attributes are defined here
  firstName: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  lastName: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING
    // allowNull defaults to true
  }
}, {
  // Other model options go here
  sequelize, // We need to pass the connection instance
  modelName: 'User' // We need to choose the model name
});
```

if its functional then

```js
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require("../your/db/file");

const User = sequelize.define('User', {
  // Model attributes are defined here
  firstName: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  lastName: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING
    // allowNull defaults to true
  }
}, {
  // Other model options go here
});
```

All this can be found in the [Sequelize models](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html) documentation